# GridView Column is becoming Empty, When UpdatePanel does postback after button click in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

GridView Column is becoming Empty, When UpdatePanel does postback after button click in ASP.NET. Is there any way to prevent updatepanel postback after the button is clicked. Please suggest!

Comment: where is your button placed ? inside update panel ?

Comment: Post your markup and code so that we can understand where is the issue.

Comment: yes button is placed inside update panel, content template

Answer (score 0):

Try to Put your code in Ispostback, whenever you initialize grid view.